# Реализация списка стран(Spinner) + номер телефона с кодом страны(EditText)

Tags: android

Привет всем! В приложении есть поле страна - это Spinner(список стран), а так же номер телефона - EditText для ввода номера. Пока это не сделано. Мне нужен список стран + в номер, в зависимости от страны должен в начале подставляться код страны. Каким образом можно это реализовать? Не знаю насколько понятно объяснил..если есть вопросы спрашивайте и помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться готовым решением [Country Code Picker (CCP)](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject). Либо создать xml со всеми кодами:

```
<string-array name="countryCodes">
<item>93,AF</item>
<item>355,AL</item>
<item>213,DZ</item>
<item>376,AD</item>
<item>244,AO</item>
<item>672,AQ</item>
<item>54,AR</item>
<item>374,AM</item>
<item>297,AW</item>
<item>61,AU</item>
<item>43,AT</item>
<item>994,AZ</item>
<item>973,BH</item>
<item>880,BD</item>
<item>375,BY</item>
<item>32,BE</item>
<item>501,BZ</item>
<item>229,BJ</item>
<item>975,BT</item>
<item>591,BO</item>
<item>387,BA</item>
<item>267,BW</item>
<item>55,BR</item>
<item>673,BN</item>
<item>359,BG</item>
<item>226,BF</item>
<item>95,MM</item>
<item>257,BI</item>
<item>855,KH</item>
<item>237,CM</item>
<item>1,CA</item>
<item>238,CV</item>
<item>236,CF</item>
<item>235,TD</item>
<item>56,CL</item>
<item>86,CN</item>
<item>61,CX</item>
<item>61,CC</item>
<item>57,CO</item>
<item>269,KM</item>
<item>242,CG</item>
<item>243,CD</item>
<item>682,CK</item>
<item>506,CR</item>
<item>385,HR</item>
<item>53,CU</item>
<item>357,CY</item>
<item>420,CZ</item>
<item>45,DK</item>
<item>253,DJ</item>
<item>670,TL</item>
<item>593,EC</item>
<item>20,EG</item>
<item>503,SV</item>
<item>240,GQ</item>
<item>291,ER</item>
<item>372,EE</item>
<item>251,ET</item>
<item>500,FK</item>
<item>298,FO</item>
<item>679,FJ</item>
<item>358,FI</item>
<item>33,FR</item>
<item>689,PF</item>
<item>241,GA</item>
<item>220,GM</item>
<item>995,GE</item>
<item>49,DE</item>
<item>233,GH</item>
<item>350,GI</item>
<item>30,GR</item>
<item>299,GL</item>
<item>502,GT</item>
<item>224,GN</item>
<item>245,GW</item>
<item>592,GY</item>
<item>509,HT</item>
<item>504,HN</item>
<item>852,HK</item>
<item>36,HU</item>
<item>91,IN</item>
<item>62,ID</item>
<item>98,IR</item>
<item>964,IQ</item>
<item>353,IE</item>
<item>44,IM</item>
<item>972,IL</item>
<item>39,IT</item>
<item>225,CI</item>
<item>81,JP</item>
<item>962,JO</item>
<item>7,KZ</item>
<item>254,KE</item>
<item>686,KI</item>
<item>965,KW</item>
<item>996,KG</item>
<item>856,LA</item>
<item>371,LV</item>
<item>961,LB</item>
<item>266,LS</item>
<item>231,LR</item>
<item>218,LY</item>
<item>423,LI</item>
<item>370,LT</item>
<item>352,LU</item>
<item>853,MO</item>
<item>389,MK</item>
<item>261,MG</item>
<item>265,MW</item>
<item>60,MY</item>
<item>960,MV</item>
<item>223,ML</item>
<item>356,MT</item>
<item>692,MH</item>
<item>222,MR</item>
<item>230,MU</item>
<item>262,YT</item>
<item>52,MX</item>
<item>691,FM</item>
<item>373,MD</item>
<item>377,MC</item>
<item>976,MN</item>
<item>382,ME</item>
<item>212,MA</item>
<item>258,MZ</item>
<item>264,NA</item>
<item>674,NR</item>
<item>977,NP</item>
<item>31,NL</item>
<item>599,AN</item>
<item>687,NC</item>
<item>64,NZ</item>
<item>505,NI</item>
<item>227,NE</item>
<item>234,NG</item>
<item>683,NU</item>
<item>850,KP</item>
<item>47,NO</item>
<item>968,OM</item>
<item>92,PK</item>
<item>680,PW</item>
<item>507,PA</item>
<item>675,PG</item>
<item>595,PY</item>
<item>51,PE</item>
<item>63,PH</item>
<item>870,PN</item>
<item>48,PL</item>
<item>351,PT</item>
<item>1,PR</item>
<item>974,QA</item>
<item>40,RO</item>
<item>7,RU</item>
<item>250,RW</item>
<item>590,BL</item>
<item>685,WS</item>
<item>378,SM</item>
<item>239,ST</item>
<item>966,SA</item>
<item>221,SN</item>
<item>381,RS</item>
<item>248,SC</item>
<item>232,SL</item>
<item>65,SG</item>
<item>421,SK</item>
<item>386,SI</item>
<item>677,SB</item>
<item>252,SO</item>
<item>27,ZA</item>
<item>82,KR</item>
<item>34,ES</item>
<item>94,LK</item>
<item>290,SH</item>
<item>508,PM</item>
<item>249,SD</item>
<item>597,SR</item>
<item>268,SZ</item>
<item>46,SE</item>
<item>41,CH</item>
<item>963,SY</item>
<item>886,TW</item>
<item>992,TJ</item>
<item>255,TZ</item>
<item>66,TH</item>
<item>228,TG</item>
<item>690,TK</item>
<item>676,TO</item>
<item>216,TN</item>
<item>90,TR</item>
<item>993,TM</item>
<item>688,TV</item>
<item>971,AE</item>
<item>256,UG</item>
<item>44,GB</item>
<item>380,UA</item>
<item>598,UY</item>
<item>1,US</item>
<item>998,UZ</item>
<item>678,VU</item>
<item>39,VA</item>
<item>58,VE</item>
<item>84,VN</item>
<item>681,WF</item>
<item>967,YE</item>
<item>260,ZM</item>
<item>263,ZW</item>
```

И сделать так

```
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Что-то мне показалось что вручную сделать легче, чем использовать CCP. Уж слишком много кода там. А как мне еще сделать вывод кода страны в начале EditText? То есть, пользователь выбирает страну, автоматически подставляется код в поле номера телефона и затем в ручную вводится сам номер.

Comment: Добавьте spinner OnItemSelectedListener и в методе onItemSelected делайте setText в Edittext с нужным кодом. Код получите из массива по номеру элемента на который кликнули

Comment: Реально спасибо! :) понятно и адекватно объяснили, если бы все так поясняли. А вот еще..у меня же записан код + название страны, как я отделю код?

Comment: Вы можете сделать два массива. Один с кодом, другой с названием страны. Размеры массива и индексы будут совпадать. В спиннер добавьте только с названием стран массив, а по клику у вас будет индекс, соответственно по нему доставайте номер из другого массива

Comment: Думаю это лучше всего будет. А не громоздко ли будет это? :)

Comment: Не громоздко. Нормально

Answer (score 0):

По уму надо делать немного по другому:

1. Берете библиотеку [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)
2. Берете список поддерживаемых стран через метод: `getSupportedRegions()`
3. Код получаете через метод `getCountryCodeForRegion(regionCode)`